# If else statement in insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sails-mssqlserver

I am facing a problem regarding syntax error in this code snippet

```
INSERT INTO tblScheduledBillGenerate(SettingConnectionId, UserId, MonthlyBill, BillGenerateDate)
VALUES ( @Id, @UserId, 
                        (   if exists (SELECT *
                            FROM tblServiceBillPackage_Audit WHERE UserId=4 and ServiceBillPackageId=(24) 
                            and Status=1 nd AuditType=N'UPDATE' ORDER BY tblServiceBillPackage_Audit.TimeStamp DESC)

BEGIN 

SELECT 1
                            
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
SELECT 2
END ), @daytoday)
```

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure USP_SCHEDULER_TestBillSchedule, Line 50
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure USP_SCHEDULER_TestBillSchedule, Line 76
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure USP_SCHEDULER_TestBillSchedule, Line 103
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
```

The problematic part of the code is given above.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  It is not clear (to me, at least) what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I want to insert 1 in that space according to a certain condition else 2
i dont know why im getting a syntax error

Comment: Done... Can you help me

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a `CASE` in your statement instead. `IF` can be used in procedures, triggers, and functions, but not inline.

```
INSERT INTO tblScheduledBillGenerate(SettingConnectionId, UserId, MonthlyBill, BillGenerateDate)
SELECT @Id as SettingConnectionId,
       @UserId as UserId, 
       CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(Id)
                    FROM tblServiceBillPackage_Audit
                   WHERE UserId=4 and ServiceBillPackageId=(24) 
                     and Status=1 and AuditType=N'UPDATE') > 0
            THEN 1
            ELSE 2 END as MonthlyBill,
       @daytoday as BillGenerateDate;
```

This should do what you're looking for.